# Extracting metadata from comment fields using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to download and process the Australian Bureaux of Meteorology weather files. So far the following Python works well, it's extracting and cleansing the data exactly as I want

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDY02122.dat", comment='#', skiprows=3, na_values=-9999.0, quotechar='"', skipfooter=1, names=['stn', 'per', 'evap', 'amax',   'amin',   'gmin',   'suns',   'rain',   'prob'], header=0, converters={'stn': str})
```

The issue is the file is overwritten daily, and the metadata which indicates what day and time the forecast was produced on is in the comment fields on the first two lines, i.e. the file contains the following data

```
# date=20131111
# time=06
[fcst_DB]
stn[7]  , per,   evap,   amax,   amin,   gmin,   suns,   rain,   prob
"001006",   0,-9999.0,   39.9,-9999.0,-9999.0,-9999.0,    4.0,  100.0
"001006",   1,-9999.0,   39.4,   26.5,-9999.0,-9999.0,    6.0,  100.0
"001006",   2,-9999.0,   35.5,   26.2,-9999.0,-9999.0,    7.0,  100.0
```

Is it possible using pandas to include the first two lines in the result. Ideally by adding a date and time column to the result and using the values 20131111 and 06 for each row in the output.

Regards
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the first two lines always be a date and time? In that case I'd suggest parsing those separately and handing the rest of the stream off to read_csv.

```
import urllib2
r = urllib2.urlopen(url)

In [29]: r = urllib2.urlopen(url)

In [30]: date = next(r).strip('# date=').rstrip()

In [31]: time = next(r).strip('# time=').rstrip()

In [32]: stamp = pd.to_datetime(x + ' ' + time)

In [33]: stamp
Out[33]: Timestamp('2013-11-12 00:00:00', tz=None)
```

Then use your code to read (I changed the `skiprows` to 1)

```
In [34]: df = pd.read_csv("ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDY02122.dat", comment='#',
             skiprows=1, na_values=-9999.0, quotechar='"', skipfooter=1,
             names=['stn', 'per', 'evap', 'amax', 'amin', 'gmin', 'suns',
                    'rain',   'prob'], header=0, converters={'stn': str})

In [43]: df['timestamp'] = stamp

In [44]: df.head()
Out[44]: 
      stn  per  evap  amax  amin  gmin  suns  rain   prob           timestamp
0  001006    0   NaN  39.9   NaN   NaN   NaN   2.9  100.0 2013-11-12 00:00:00
1  001006    1   NaN  35.8  25.8   NaN   NaN   7.0  100.0 2013-11-12 00:00:00
2  001006    2   NaN  37.0  25.5   NaN   NaN   4.0   71.4 2013-11-12 00:00:00
3  001006    3   NaN  39.0  26.0   NaN   NaN   1.0   60.0 2013-11-12 00:00:00
4  001006    4   NaN  41.2  26.1   NaN   NaN   0.0   40.0 2013-11-12 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for that, yes they will always be a date and time so your code works nicely. Plus extra points for answering my next two questions at the same time, how to add a constant column and how to set the timezone :)